# Operating system error 21 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, operating-system, database-administration

i have created one data file in drive but later when i am accessing that data file it showing OS error 21 and when i check consistency of DB by CHECKDB command i got below error i have explore lot to resolve by i haven't conclude anything.how i can solve this error

> Msg 1823, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A database snapshot cannot be created because it failed to start.
>   Msg 1823, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   A database snapshot cannot be created because it failed to start.
>   Msg 7928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The database snapshot for online checks could not be created. Either the reason is given in a previous error or one of the underlying volumes does not support sparse files or alternate streams. Attempting to get exclusive access to run checks offline.
>   Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.
>   Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
>   The operating system returned error 21(The device is not ready.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'D:\RPLMUMSRV212\PROC_DATA.ndf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Did you run out of disk space?

Comment: no , 459 GB FREE SPACE still available sir

Comment: On all drives ?

Comment: space is very low on drive where sql server is install but rest 3 drive have huge space

Comment: I hope you have a good database backup then!

Comment: Yse sir i took backups

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for an answer on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)